# SQL Calculate (time) gap between occurrences in a log

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequences

I have tables that record when certain items were sent or returned to a particular location, and I want to work out the intervals between each time a particular item is returned.

Sample data:

```
Item   ReturnDate:
Item1, 20120101
Item1, 20120201
Item1, 20120301
Item2, 20120401
Item2, 20120601
```

So in this case, we can see that the there was a month gap until Item 1 was returned the first time, and another month before it was returned the second time. Item 2 came back after 2 months.

My starting  point is:

```
Select r1.Item, r1.ReturnDate, r2.Item, r2.ReturnDate, DateDiff(m, r1.ReturnDate, r2.ReturnDate)
from Returns r1
inner join Returns r2 on r2.VehicleNo = r1.VehicleNo
```

However, in the this sample, each item is compared to every other instance where it has been returned - and not just the next one. So I need to limit this query so it will only compare adjacent returns.

One solution is to tag each return with an count (of the number of times that item has been returned):

```
Item   ReturnDate, ReturnNo:
Item1, 20120101,   1
Item1, 20120201,   2
Item1, 20120301,   3
Item2, 20120401,   1
Item2, 20120601,   2
```

This would enable me to use the following T-SQL (or similar):

```
Select r1.Item, r1.ReturnDate, r2.Item, r2.ReturnDate, DateDiff(m, r1.ReturnDate, r2.ReturnDate)
from Returns r1
inner join Returns r2 on r2.VehicleNo = r1.VehicleNo 
and (r1.ReturnNo + 1 = r2.ReturnNo)
```

My first question is whether the is a sensible/optimal approach or whether there is a better approach?

Secondly, what is the easiest/slickest means of calculating the ReturnNo?

Comment: Can you tell us a little about your table structure?  And do you need the return number for something else?

Comment: @NicoleCastle I was trying to keep the explanation generic rather than provide live DDL with more specific and less helpful terminology. Let's just say that there is a table that records the receipt of items from outside (usually the customer) and that we want to analyse the intervals between each receipt of the same items. Item and ReturnDate are all that is relevant in this case.

Comment: @NicoleCastle ... and no, I don't need the ReturnNo for anything else - it was simply to help me compare the next return for each item.

Comment: Thanks to Dominic and Richard, not just for their answers (never used ROWNUMBER/PARTITION before) but also for the introduction to SQLFiddle.com which looks like a fantastic resource.

Comment: SQLFiddle is great.  Make sure you check out the "Text to DDL" button at the top - I just copied your sample data into that rather than coming up with the DDL myself.

Comment: Wow, awesome, I didn't know about that feature myself. Thanks, @Richard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, use ROW_NUMBER() to do exactly what you want:

```
WITH RankedReturn AS
(
  SELECT Item, ReturnDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ReturnDate DESC) AS ReturnNo
  FROM Returns
)
SELECT * FROM RankedReturn
```

Obviously, now that you have your CTE you can put whatever you need in the outer SELECT. I would use an OUTER APPLY for this:

```
WITH RankedReturn AS
(
  SELECT Item, ReturnDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ReturnDate DESC) AS ReturnNo
  FROM Returns
)
SELECT rOuter.Item, rOuter.ReturnDate, DATEDIFF(month, prev.PrevDate, ReturnDate) AS Months
FROM RankedReturn rOuter
OUTER APPLY 
  (
    SELECT ReturnDate AS PrevDate 
    FROM RankedReturn rInner 
    WHERE rOuter.Item = rInner.Item AND rOuter.ReturnNo = rInner.ReturnNo - 1
  ) prev
```

Oops, and the [SQL Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d384/9).

**Edited because the month difference calculation was backwards; fixed now**

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way of calculating the ReturnNo would be to use `OVER`:

```
SELECT [Item], [ReturnDate], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [ReturnDate]) AS ReturnNumber
FROM Returns
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e18ad/1/0

You could also attempt to make use of the [techniques for calculating a running total](http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx) to work out the difference between two rows.

Comment: I wish I could give you extra for the 'calculating the running total' link which is interesting reading in it's own right.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
select  itemNo,
        dt,
        DATEDIFF(day, previousDt, dt) as daysSince
from    (select itemNo, 
                dt,
                (select top 1 dt from testTable where itemNo = outerTbl.itemNo and dt < outerTbl.dt order by dt desc) as previousDt
        from    testTable as outerTbl
        ) as x
```

... and here's a bit of setup code for anybody else testing a solution to this

```
create table testTable(
itemNo nvarchar(20),
dt datetime)
go

insert into testTable values('Item1', '2012-01-01');
insert into testTable values('Item1', '2012-02-01');
insert into testTable values('Item1', '2012-03-01');
insert into testTable values('Item2', '2012-04-01');
insert into testTable values('Item2', '2012-05-01');
go
```